# Resizing Chat Bubble on Unordered List

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, list, chat

I have an unordred list which acts as a chat platform. With each "message" appended to the list by the user, I have it appear with a chat bubble behind, however, the chat bubble remains the same size with every message appended, meaning that if the message contains a certain amount of characters, it appears outside of the bubble. Is there a way for a chat bubble to resize itself due to the size of the message? Preferrably after about 25 characters, I'd like the message to start a new line and the bubble to expand in height. On the other side, if a message is only 5 characters long, the chat bubble would resize to fit that.

A picture to illustrate the problm is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YG7P.jpg

Here is my Jquery/ Javascript

```
 $('#submit').click(function(){
  var message = $('#typetextbox').val();
  if (message.replace(/ /g, '')){
      var positions = makeNewPosition();
      var el = $('<li>'+message+'</li>');
      el.attr('gridpos', positions[0].toString()+"x"+positions[1].toString())
      el.css('left', positions[1] * window.li_width);
      el.css('top', positions[0] * window.li_height);
      $('#messagebox').append(el);


      setTimeout(function() {
          el.fadeOut();
          var gridpos = el.attr('gridpos');
          delete window.grid[gridpos];
      }, 4000 );


  }
  $("#typetextbox").val("");
});

});
 window.grid = {};
window.li_height = 20;
window.li_width = 200;
function makeNewPosition(){


var h = Math.floor($(window).height()/window.li_height);
var w = Math.floor($(window).width()/window.li_width);

var nh = Math.floor(Math.random() * h);
var nw = Math.floor(Math.random() * w);
var gridpos = nh.toString() + "x" + nw.toString();
if(typeof window.grid[gridpos] == 'undefined'){
    return [nh,nw];
}else{

    return makeNewPosition();
}
```

Here's my CSS:

```
li{
height: 24px;
width: 220px;
margin: 2px;
padding: 5px;
position: absolute;
z-index: -2;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
color: #FFF;
background-image: url(Images/chat-bubble-left-flick.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: -25px center;

}

ul{
list-style:none;
}
```

Sorry for providing a lot of code, but I'm not sure where my problem lies/fits. I'm assuming it's something to correct in Javascript rather than using a background image? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you add a fiddle with your problem?

Comment: I'm afraid when I copy and paste my code in to fiddle, strangely even the basics dont work. I have tried. 

Basically whenever the characters in the message surpass the width of the 'li' (220px), they grow outside the message box. I am hoping to get a message box that moulds around the message itself.

Any ideas?

Comment: @Mritunjay I've added a link to illustrate the problem.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Chat bubble size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269852/chat-bubble-size)

Answer (score 0):

`height: 24px;` is the reason, use `min-height: 24px;` instead.

Is `position: absolute;` required?